# Google Forms adds ' in front of input data

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form which has 5 inputs. The first of which is a text-string containing Today's date, generated by iMacros for Chrome.

If I add say **2017-05-07**, it shows up as **'2017-05-07** in my spreadsheet. So my formula is not able to match this, due to the **'**-character being added.

I have tried re-creating the Google Form from scratch, and the issue still persists. I have also prompted the value in iMacros, and it shows up without the **'**-character as it is supposed to.

What could be the issue here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an interesting issue, but your question is probably considered "Off-topic" for Stack Overflow.  You can modify the answers in your spreadsheet immediately after they are submitted by using an "On Form Submit" trigger.  If you are asking about how to configure iMacros in Chrome, that's a question about Web Applications, which there is a separate community for.  [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This question only pertains to the Google Forms submission, but I will see what I can find out about the **On Form Submit**, thank you.

Everything else is working fine, except this one issue that seems very strange to me, and it adds it solely for this input field, despite having re-created the entire form.

Comment: Will iMacros in Chrome work with a question in Google Forms that is a date question?  You defined the Google Form question as a text field, so it's doing what it's supposed to do, enter the answer as text.

Comment: Is it not able to do that without adding an **'** in front of the text-string?

However, I was able to circumvent it by adding VALUE() to my formula in my google spreadsheet, so that it is able to interpret the text.